# PHP Codeigniter If else value always result in null

Tags: php, codeigniter, if-statement, null

Hi i am developing an event management site and i use if else statement on my controller to navigate 2 view pages (a view page with a file attachment and a view page without a file attachment) my problem is everytime i execute the if else statement from my controller i always end up on the situation where there is no file attached on the database (null)

Here is my controller :

```
public function viewevent(){

$id = $this->uri->segment(3);

$data['events'] = $this->EventModel->getEventII($id);

$check = $this-$this->EventModel->getEventII($id);   

if($check->event_file == null){

$this->load->view('include/schoolrep/toppage', $data);
$this->load->view('include/schoolrep/header', $data);
$this->load->view('schoolrep/viewevent2', $data); // loads page where there is no file attached
$this->load->view('include/schoolrep/footer', $data);
}else{

$this->load->view('include/schoolrep/toppage', $data);
$this->load->view('include/schoolrep/header', $data);
$this->load->view('schoolrep/viewevent', $data); //loads page where there is file attached
$this->load->view('include/schoolrep/footer', $data);
}
```

}

here is my model

```
public function getEventII($id){
  $q = $this->db->get_where('tblevents',array('event_id'=>$id));
  return $q->row();

}
```

as you can see on my if else statement i am checking my event_file column from the database if its null or not but i always ended up loading the view file where there is no file attached or (event_file == null) even though there is.

Thanks.

Comment: try `is_null($check->event_file)` or `$check->event_file === null`

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix ok will give a try thanks

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix problem still occur

Comment: can you check the $check variable what it is giving.

Comment: I figured it would, it's just that `null == false == 0 == '' == []` etc...

Comment: @itsme tried using the var_dump($check); and it gave me a int(0) output

Comment: problem solved omg it's just that my declaration of $check has errors i double typed $this->

Comment: You must have error reporting and display error off?  no

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix problem solved thanks mate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can change `this` line to

```
 $check =  $this-$this->EventModel->getEventII($id);
```

this

```
$check =  $this->EventModel->getEventII($id);
```

Comment: Yes this one! thanks a lot i just figured it out also thanks mate

Comment: yes i was about to but the site said i can accept your answer after 1 min but its done answer accepted thanks